# Siri Shortcuts: How do I create a UI for the intent parameters of an iOS shortcut?

Tags: ios, sirikit, ios12, sirishortcuts

I'm trying to create an INIntent to be set up with the new iOS Shortcuts app in iOS 12. I have read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit) and watched the apple [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/211) about it.

I have managed to set everything up and the shortcuts work well, however I can’t seem to figure out how to make customizable options that the user can edit when setting up the shortcut. An example of this would be how the Calendar app’s shortcuts are set up:

[image: Calendar shortcut setup]

Notice the options for Get, Add Filter, Sort by, etc..

I know I can add parameters to the intents in the *Intents.intentdefeniton* file, but those parameters needs to be set from the app itself before the interaction is donated to the iOS system via SiriKit.

Regardless of what I do the Intent just shows up empty without options.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems that these stuff are set up by developers of shortcuts\workflow app internally. Only predefined apps (apple apps\evernote\todoist\facebook\bear\etc) seems to have such options. Would be glad if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry to bring you bad news, but there is no way to do that. The apps that appear there (like Trello, Overcast, Pocket, etc...) were already supported by Workflow.app before Shortcuts.app was released.

You can try to work around it by [calling URL Schemes directly](https://thesweetsetup.com/apps-weve-recommended-also-work-shortcuts/) but it might not be the solution you are after.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I really hope they release such a feature, it would make shortcuts more useful for developers.

Comment: I agree with you, but I also understand that it creates another set of problems regarding UX. This was a good first step, maybe next year? :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create an Intents UI Extension for this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_ui_extension